# Does php have any string functions which swap substrings?

Tags: php, string

I am writing a geometry application that includes proofs. The basic flow right now is that a user enters an answer, and this answerstring is compared to the "correct" answerstring. The application is in the early stages right now, but I can already see that some features of the application would require less code if I found the right php function. For example, in a multistep proof, suppose in one step of a multistep geometry proof, the answer in the database is:

```
AB ≅ AC //(as AB &cong; AC)
```

The php file that processes this trims all whitespace using `trim` and `str_replace`. A user that inputs all of the following as an answer would be correct:

```
AB &cong; AC
AB&cong;AC
AB &cong;AC
AB&cong; AC
```

However, even though the following would be correct in the real world, my php file (initially, before I made changes) considered the following "incorrect":

```
AC &cong; AB //and all permutations missing whitespace
```

Now I use a combination of `strpos`, `stripos`, `strlen`, and `substr` to account for the asymmetry of equivalent answers (e.g., A=B same as B=A) but it adds lots of code.

Is there any string function in php which swaps substrings. That is, given 2 strings as follows:

```
$AnswerString1 = "AB&cong;AC";

$AnswerString2 = "AC&cong;AB";
```

is there any php string function which swaps substrings hypothetically like this:

```
$SwappedAnswerString2 = swap($AnswerString2, "AB", "AC");
```

such that now:

```
$AnswerString1 = $SwappedAnswerString2;
```

?

Comment: Explode() to an array on `&cong;`, array_walk() or array_map() with trim(), and then sort?

Comment: The explode() method sounds like a good suggestion, because not only does it allow sorting, but if the user does not even enter &cong; the explode array will be empty, which would serve as another check for the validity of the answer